Creating an ADF Delete activity expression that does nothing if target folder does not exist
I have a source folder that is uploaded to a directory 'load' in an ADLS container. I created an ADF delete activity with an expression @concat(item().container, '/load/', activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0]['name']) which takes the output of a Get Metadata activity. This works well, but if no folder is uploaded another day it fails because it could not find the folder in 'load' directory.
What I tried:
I modified the expression to include an if statement @if(not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems, '[]')), concat(item().layer, '/load/', activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0]['name']), null )
But I get the error below:
'The expression 'if(not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems, '[]')),
concat(item().layer, '/load/', activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0]['name']), null
)' cannot be evaluated because array index '0' cannot be selected from empty array.'
I am a bit confused because I included in the expression that it should do nothing (null) if target folder does not exist. I have tried '', null and [] in place of '[]' but still gives the same error. Note that I am not able to use an IF Condition activity as I am already working inside an IF Condition activity within an ForEach activity. So I just want to code the condition Any help please


Try placing all your current activities an if condition under "True" condition where condition gets input from a Get metadata activity. Configure this additional metadata activity to "exists" property as mentioned in URL below
https://azurelib.com/how-to-check-if-file-exist-in-azure-data-factory-adf/
This would make your workflow to work only when there is a file/folder available in the expected location
If you are unable to use "if" condition, create an child pipeline for those activities and use Execute pipeline activity in foreach/if


In the above expression, you are comparing empty Get meta data array [] with string '[]' which results False. So, the second expression will be executed with an empty array where array should not be empty. That's why you got the above error.
To achieve your requirement, do the below changes in the delete activity.
First, go to the delete activity dataset and create parameters for container, folder and filename like below.

Divide your file path in your expression into 3 parts. Give the respective container expression to container parameter and folder expression to folder parameter and filename expression to filename parameter.
Here, I have given fixed strings to container and folder parameters. You can give your dynamic expression involving current item() as per your requirement.
As your main requirement is to give null if child items array is empty, modify the expression like below and give it to filename parameter.
@if(not(equals(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems), '[]')), concat(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0]['name']), null)


Pipeline run when Get meta data child items array is not empty.

The above file will be deleted after the pipeline run.
The pipeline run when Child items array is empty.

Nothing will be deleted as required null given to the parameter.
